# Vaadin 14: Exchange Combobox Dropdown icon

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In a Vaadin 14 application I wanted to exchange this standard icon at a combobox:

[image: Vaadin combobox with standard icon]

for another icon (and achieved the goal, but I think that my way is not the best / nicest).

My full use case is assembling a list, some buttons and a combobox to create this sortable multi-select-list:
[image: sortable multi-select-list in Vaadin]

The user can add a new value to the list by selecting the new value in the combobox below.

To exchange the standard icon for the combobox (`--lumo-icons-dropdown = \ea18`, an arrow showing down) for a plus-icon, I used this code: `combobox.getElement().getStyle().set("--lumo-icons-dropdown", "\"\\ea23\"");` (yes, all the quotes and backslashes are as shown)

This works fine (as you can see in the screenshot), but it feels incorrect to overwrite an icon.

Is there another (better) way to exchange the standard dropdown icon at a Vaadin combobox for another icon?

Comment: I wouldn’t say this is incorrect in any major way. It’s not perhaps something that we’ve considered to be the primary way of changing the icons (we don’t actually have a primary way at the moment, something we need to solve in the future), but it works and is straightforward.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information that there is no "official" primary way. Then I'll keep it as it is and won't search for an alternative. :-)

Comment: Side note: I would apply a CSS class to combobox and use (not hard-coded) CSS using the CSS class as selector to change the icon. Makes it easier to adapt the icon afterwards.